# How to fill NA values with applying condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, imputation, data-science-experience

I am trying to replace null values with 0 by applying certain conditions. Here is the code to generate the dataset.

```
data = {'month': ['2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-04-01', '2022-05-01', '2022-06-01', '2022-07-01', '2022-08-01'], 'Date1': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-01'], 'Date2': ['2022-02-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-04-01', '2022-04-01', '2022-04-01', '2022-04-01', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 'Name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 'num': [1234, 1234, 1234, 456, 456, 456, 456, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 'sales': ['MN', 'MN', 'MN', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL'], 'Num1': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 44.0, 44.0, 44.0, 44.0], 'Num2': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 29.0, 29.0, 29.0, 29.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

         month       Date1       Date2 Name   num sales  Num1  Num2
0   2022-01-01  2022-01-01  2022-02-01    A  1234    MN   NaN   NaN
1   2022-02-01  2022-01-01  2022-02-01    A  1234    MN   NaN   NaN
2   2022-03-01  2022-01-01  2022-02-01    A  1234    MN   NaN   NaN
3   2022-01-01  2022-01-01  2022-04-01    B   456    CA   NaN   NaN
4   2022-02-01  2022-01-01  2022-04-01    B   456    CA   NaN   NaN
5   2022-03-01  2022-01-01  2022-04-01    B   456    CA   NaN   NaN
6   2022-04-01  2022-01-01  2022-04-01    B   456    CA   NaN   NaN
7   2022-05-01  2022-05-01         NaN    C   NaN    FL  44.0  29.0
8   2022-06-01  2022-05-01         NaN    C   NaN    FL  44.0  29.0
9   2022-07-01  2022-05-01         NaN    C   NaN    FL  44.0  29.0
10  2022-08-01  2022-05-01         NaN    C   NaN    FL  44.0  29.0
```

So,  I want to replace the null values in the num column for certain rows if month-date1 <=2, and I want to replace null values in Num1, and Num2 column for certain rows if month-date2 <=2. If it is greater than 2, then don't replace it with 0.

So, I was wondering how can I implement these steps in python?

This is the expected outcome
[image]

Comment: Share expected output ?

Comment: Replace `null`, or `NaN`? The two are different values.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of the expected outcome. I need to replace null values with zero with the given condition described as above. @Psidom

Comment: What do you mean by `month-date1 <=2` ? 2 month or 2 days?

Comment: It's for a month as the date are monthly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use where the condition

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'month': ['2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-04-01', '2022-05-01', '2022-06-01', '2022-07-01', '2022-08-01'], 'Date1': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-01'], 'Date2': ['2022-02-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-04-01', '2022-04-01', '2022-04-01', '2022-04-01', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 'Name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 'num': [1234, 1234, 1234, 456, 456, 456, 456, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 'sales': ['MN', 'MN', 'MN', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL'], 'Num1': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 44.0, 44.0, 44.0, 44.0], 'Num2': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 29.0, 29.0, 29.0, 29.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date1'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date1'])
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date2'])
df['Num1'] = np.where(np.logical_and(df['Date2'].dt.month <=2, np.isnan(df['Num1'])),0, df['Num1'])
df['Num2'] = np.where(np.logical_and(df['Date2'].dt.month <=2, np.isnan(df['Num2'])),0, df['Num2'])
print(df)
```

in the above example, I am considering the month of `Date1 and Date2`

if you want to consider month columns also then you can follow the below code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'month': ['2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-04-01', '2022-05-01', '2022-06-01', '2022-07-01', '2022-08-01'], 'Date1': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-01'], 'Date2': ['2022-02-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-04-01', '2022-04-01', '2022-04-01', '2022-04-01', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 'Name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 'num': [1234, 1234, 1234, 456, 456, 456, 456, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 'sales': ['MN', 'MN', 'MN', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL'], 'Num1': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 44.0, 44.0, 44.0, 44.0], 'Num2': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 29.0, 29.0, 29.0, 29.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#print(df)
df['Date1'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date1'])
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date2'])
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'])
#print(df)
df['Num1'] = np.where(np.logical_and(df['month'].dt.month <=2,df['Date1'].dt.month <=2, np.isnan(df['Num1'])),0, df['Num1'])
df['Num2'] = np.where(np.logical_and(df['month'].dt.month <=2,df['Date2'].dt.month <=2, np.isnan(df['Num2'])),0, df['Num2'])
print(df)
```

Comment: I used the same code and I got an error **RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object**. Are we missing something?

Comment: What is your dataframe length (size of the data)

Comment: I am not sure that. Honestly, I don't know how to check that. I just copied your code and paste in VS code and hit run but it did not work.

Comment: https://onecompiler.com/python/3yauyufp9 here you can check working code.

Comment: yeah, it is working over there but could not figure out why it is not working on vs code. I checked the recursion depth on the webpage as well. It is using the same depth as in the vs code. 
Is there a other way to do it?